# Why is git still trying to add the classpath files?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am working on a windows computer with cygwin using git with eclipse...

git keeps trying to add the following files

```
modified:   EJB/.classpath
modified:   WAR/.classpath
```

but if you look in my .gitignore it looks like this..

```
Flex/src/generated/
work/
logs/
build/
EJB/classes/
WAR/WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/
.classpath
EJB/.classpath
com.genuitec.eclipse.persistence.jpa.prefs
WAR/.classpath
 WAR/.classpath
 EJB/.classpath
```

what else can I do or try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have added those `.classpath` files to git earlier, and git is already tracking them, so adding them to `.gitignore` is not sufficient.

You need to stop tracking it in your repo. Try

```
git rm -r --cached EJB/.classpath WAR/.classpath
git commit -m "untracking .classpath files"
```

And after this, `gitignore` will ignore the changes to them.